# How to fix rails 3.0.1 on Netbeans 6.9.1 for Ruby 1.9.2

Tags: macos, ruby-1.9, netbeans-6.9, ruby-on-rails-3

I have Mac os 10.5.8 and Ruby 1.9.2p0, Rails 3.0.1, Netbeans 6.9.1 installed. When i run the project by creating it from existing source code, it says

> Error opening script file: /usr/local/src/demo_app/script/server (No such file or directory)

Before it i have edited project in TextMate and run successfully over terminal. I know that with Rails 3.0 there is no script/server but rails server, to run the project. How to fix this issue, is there any way to configure RUN command in netbeans or any other idea is most welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Help me to get out of it..its very painful to uninstall current version of ruby & rails and reinstall their old versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. Here is what you can try:

1. Go to the folder where the gem `ruby-debug-ide-0.4.6` (or whatever your version is) is installed.
2. In the `lib` folder, edit the file `ruby-debug.rb`
3. Locate the method `def debug_program(options)`.
4. Look for the line `bt = debug_load(Debugger::PROG_SCRIPT, options.stop, options.load_mode)`
5. Just before that line, add `Debugger.const_set('PROG_SCRIPT', './rails server')`
6. Save file and restart Netbeans.
   You may see a warning that constant is being set or something when NetBeans starts the debugger, just ignore that.

Also, you should upgrade to using Rails 3.0.3

Comment: I am not able to find out the folder where gem ruby-debug-ide-0.4.6 is installed.But when i search by this name in spotlight it leads me to the plugin folder of Aptana RadRails (its also installed) which is its own, i doubt whether the netbeans has the same folder or ruby-debug.rb file.

Comment: Search for `ruby-debug*` and post results

Answer (score 0):

I have read that Neatbeans 6.9.1 doesn't support Rails 3 as the underlying command line tools have changed in Rails but the changes were too late for the Netbeans release cycle.

I would recommend, if you are using MRI Ruby (1.8.*) or YARV Ruby (1.9.*) switching to [Rubymine](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/) if you need an IDE either temporarily or permanently as it fully supports Rails 3 and all of the command line tools that support it. It has good integration with [git](http://git-scm.com/) too and many other very useful version control tools. If you are using any other versions of Ruby I can't say if you will have much success because I don't know.

It also has good refactoring tools and debugging support if you need it.

You can get a temporary 30 day licence from the home page and also keep up to date with development changes at the [EAP](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/RUBYDEV/RubyMine+EAP) page, they also offer free licenses if you are doing open source development.

For mac os 10.5.8 you might want to have a look at [this thread](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RUBY-6360) if you have difficulty installing it.

I don't expect a bounty for this answer as its not an exact answer to your question but its a possible solution.